# Uploading a file to a Django PUT handler using the requests library

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have a REST PUT request to upload a file using the Django REST framework. Whenever I am uploading a file using the Postman REST client it works fine:

[image: Postman configuration]

But when I try to do this with my code:

```
import requests
API_URL = "http://123.316.118.92:8888/api/"

API_TOKEN  = "1682b28041de357d81ea81db6a228c823ad52967"

URL = API_URL + 'configuration/configlet/31'
#files = {
files = {'file': open('configlet.txt','rb')}
print URL
print "Update Url ==-------------------"
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain','Authorization':API_TOKEN}
resp = requests.put(URL,files=files,headers = headers)
print resp.text
print resp.status_code
```

I am getting an error on the server side:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/configuration/31/

"'file'"
```

I am passing file as key but still getting above error please do let me know what might I am doing wrong here.

This is how my Django server view looks

```
def put(self, request,id,format=None):
    configlet = self.get_object(id)
    configlet.config_path.delete(save=False)
    file_obj = request.FILES['file']
    configlet.config_path = file_obj
    file_content = file_obj.read()
    params = parse_file(file_content)
    configlet.parameters = json.dumps(params)
    logger.debug("File content: "+str(file_content))
    configlet.save()
```

Comment: Are you sure this worked with PostMan? Django's `request.FILES` is **only** ever set if the method used is `POST`, not `PUT`.

Comment: I don't have 10 credit otherwise I would have posted postman image already

Comment: Post a link to the image and we can edit it in.

Comment: PLease find attached link http://s17.postimg.org/62okc6h8f/snipping.png

Comment: Ah, I missed that the Django REST framework appears to [override the standard Django behaviour](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/) and allows `.FILES` to exist on PUT requests too.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to send a `multipart/form-data` body. You should *not* be setting the content-type of the whole request to `text/plain` here; set only the mime-type of the one part:

```
files = {'file': ('configlet.txt', open('configlet.txt','rb'), 'text/plain')}
headers = {'Authorization': API_TOKEN}
resp = requests.put(URL, files=files, headers=headers)
```

This leaves setting the `Content-Type` header for the request as a whole to the library, and using `files` sets that to `multipart/form-data` for you.

Comment: @PriyaDubey: can you share more information about your django method then?

Comment: @PriyaDubey: the combination of `files` and setting the `Content-Type` header is most certainly incorrect, but without more information it is hard to state exactly what your PUT handler expects.

Comment: @PriyaDubey: right, updated my answer then. You cannot use `PUT` *and* use `request.FILES`. That dictionary is deliberately empty unless you use POST.

Comment: @PriyaDubey: I've testing Postman, setting up the settings as your screenshot, and my answer produces the exact same request; e.g. your only mistake was to set the `Content-Type` header manually.

Comment: if I am not passing content type still it I a getting same  error can you update the answer with the request you are using

Comment: @PriyaDubey: Change the URL in both your `requests` code and in Postman to `http://httpbin.org/put` and you'll see that the exact same data is sent.